# Pull in the oldest stash

Tags: git, git-stash

Using following stash list how you pull in the oldest stash while ensuring that you maintain it in the stash.

The list is :

```
stash@{0}: WIP on feature/feature1: 2f78364 New text
stash@{1}: WIP on feature/feature1: 2f78364 New text
```

Options are:

1. git stash apply stash@{0}
2. git stash apply stash@{1}
3. git stash pop stash@{0}
4. git stash pop stash@{1}

I answered as 1, but the correct answer is 2. By framing the question as oldest stash, I thought the first entry which is stash@{0} is the oldest entry which is apparently not. Correct answer is 2.

How?

Comment: The stash@{1} is older than stash@{1} by looking id you can tell and the question says pull in the oldest stash, so how stash@{1} can be the old. @knittl

Comment: Just an advise: You can live without stashing for most use cases. Instead, even if it's just something small, create a branch. You can cherry-pick commits between branches and rebase them when the main branch evolves.

Answer (score 2):

`stash@{0}` is the most recent (newest) stash, `stash@{1}` is "one older", `stash@{2}` is even older. The oldest stash is the stash with the highest number.

That's how Git defines it, there is no "how"; Quote from the docs

> `stash@{0}` is the most recently created stash, `stash@{1}` is the one before it, `stash@{2.hours.ago}` is also possible

Comment: Okay was not aware that start@{0} will be most recent, I was thinking, {0} is the first and new will be {1}. Thanks for clearing that up. @Knittl

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
off_by_one=$(wc -l <$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/logs/refs/stash)
oldest=$(($off_by_one-1))
git stash apply stash@{$oldest}
```